# Is this the best way to buffer audio in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

I have streaming audio in wave format being played out through html5 capabilities of firefox. Because some of our users complained about choppy audio we decided to come up with a strategy for measuring if the rate of the audio was good enough to sustain playback. We first tried the canplaythrough event, but apparently the browser was too optimistic about it and it did not quite work. Here is some code that I am proposing using jquery. I am a js/jquery beginner so i wanted to see if anyone had any better ideas.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var previous_buffer = 0;
var start_time = (new Date()).getTime();

// function to check how fast buffer is
function checkBufferSpeed() {
    // if we havent started buffering yet, return
    if (this.buffered.length < 1)
    {
        return;
    }
    // get the current buffer status
    var current_buffer = this.buffered.end(0);
    console.log("current_buffer:" + current_buffer);
    // if we get the same current buffer twice, browser is done buffering
    if (current_buffer > 0 && current_buffer == previous_buffer)
    {
        this.play();
        $("#audio").off("progress");
        return;
    }
    // get the time spent
    var time_spent = ((new Date()).getTime() - start_time)/1000;
    console.log("time_spent:" + time_spent);
    // if we buffered faster than time spent, play
    if (current_buffer > time_spent)
    {
        this.play();
        $("#audio").off("progress");
        return;
    }
    previous_buffer = current_buffer
}

$("#audio").on("progress", checkBufferSpeed);
});
```

also, the reason i am not checking the audio elements duration variable because firefox seems to always report that as infinite, unless the stream is already cached.

also, it seems like firefox always fires 2 progress events even if the stream is fully available in cache which is why i have the check to see if i have the same buffer twice and if so, to just play the sound.

is there a chance that the browser will never fire progress events?
any enhancements I could make to this code to make it better?